# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDABuilder

Tags: java, bots, discord-jda

Hello First time posting so sorry if this is bad
I keep running into this error code, I have tried reinstalling different versions of JDA and the only one that works is JDA-4.3.0_333, I am using eclipse. I even reinstalled eclipse to the for developers version. I have restarded and rewritten multiple times runnning into the same error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDABuilder
at threeStringsMusicBot.StartUp.main(StartUp.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)

```
package threeStringsMusicBot;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.OnlineStatus;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Activity;

public class StartUp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException{ //Login Exception allows for bot to log into bot account'
        JDABuilder threeStrings = JDABuilder.createDefault("#######"); //create new bot with JDABuilder class and give it our bot token
        threeStrings.setActivity(Activity.playing("The Lute!")); //set bot activity
        threeStrings.setStatus(OnlineStatus.ONLINE); //set bit status to online
        threeStrings.build(); //build(); function calls for bot to login
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Figured it out, I needed to be on JAVA 1.8

Comment: Please close your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

needed to be on JAVA 1.8, I was previously on the current version of java but this version of JDA needed java 1.8.